# How to compile C code using NDK for Android Device (ARM)?

Tags: c, android-ndk

I need to perform the following steps:

- write a simple counter that keeps resetting itself after overflow in C/C++
- compile and push that code into the phone via ADB
- run it as a regular executable in background via ADB shell

how to compile the above C code using NDK toolchain? I found a couple of similar links but none of them give simple and complete steps to do so.

If there is a link with complete steps please do refer me to the same.

Compile Environment: Ubuntu, compile should be done via console not any IDE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're right, I made a mistake, I had not even tested it and gave me the
same error, is due to the entry point of the "main", as this has not
changed but I hope this works for you. Anyway check the symbol table "nm",
the real-time execution "strace", you can even use gdbserver.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        printf ("hello world");
        return 0;
}


export NDK_ROOT=your_ndk_path
export PATH=$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin:$PATH
export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc -I$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include -Wl,-rpath-link=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib -Wl,-L$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib -Wl,-lc -o test test.c

If ld return with erros like "... ld: error: cannot open... : No such file or directory"
try this for your losed files:
ln -s $NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtend_android.o
ln -s $NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o
```

Comment: Thanks! But, could you please help me to understand "Anyway check the symbol table "nm", the real-time execution "strace", you can even use gdbserver." I haven't used these before

Comment: Thanks for the answer it works, but isn't there a proper way to resolve these links:ln -s $NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtend_android.o
ln -s $NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib/crtbegin_dynamic.o ..also we don't need -Wl,-rpath-link=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib..is it there at runtime?

Comment: Well in a UNIX environment using bash and assuming NDK_ROOT is a variable, $NDK_ROOT access its value, I do not know why this does not work for you. -Wl is to specify to the compiler that "the next option" is for the linker.

Comment: -rpath-link is for using ELF or SunOS, the difference between "-rpath" and "-rpath-link" is that directories specified by "-rpath" options are included in the executable and used at runtime, whereas the -rpath-link option is only effective at link time.

Comment: Yes, but how will your -rpath-link work this path should be present on the target machine..without option too my code compiles successfully and what is the purpose of -Wl, -lc

Answer (score 1):

```
I use gcc4.8 and android API-level18
usin this you can try:

First way using command line.
export NDK_ROOT=your_ndk_path
export PATH=$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin:$PATH
export CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc
export LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld
export CPPFLAGS=-I$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include
export CFLAGS="-nostdlib" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib/ -L$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib"
export LIBS="-lc"
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc  -nostdlib -o test test.c

If run "file test" you should see this:
test: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped


Second way using autotools.
export PATH=$NDK_ROOT/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.8/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin:$PATH
./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi CC=arm-linux-androideabi-gcc LD=arm-linux-androideabi-ld CPPFLAGS="-I$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/include" CFLAGS="-nostdlib" LDFLAGS="-Wl,-rpath-link=$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib/ -L$NDK_ROOT/platforms/android-18/arch-arm/usr/lib" LIBS="-lc"
make
http://embelinux.blogspot.com/2013/09/autotools1-hola-mundo-la-autotools.html


Third way using android developers ndk full feature.
Read Android.mk file syntax specification. This document describes the
syntax of Android.mk build file written to describe your C and C++ source
files to the Android NDK.
http://www.kandroid.org/ndk/docs/ANDROID-MK.html
```

Comment: Hi, could you please explain the CFLAGS and LDFLAGS..the compile fails..if I include <stdio.h>..as it doesn't fetches the header from platform/../... folder rather it finds one in .../toolchain.../include-fixed/stdio.h that further includes a header file which is not found..also, if I do not include any file and write a simple main funtion, it compiles but gives a segmentation fault when executed on android..

Comment: I gets `test.c:1:19: fatal error: stdio.h: No such file or directory
 #include <stdio.h>` what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

gdbserver is to debug an application running on the Android device and can
control gdb from the PC using a TCP connection. gdb (The GNU Debugger)
need the debugging symbols.

When you compile an application the compiler puts all the symbols defined
in something called as symbol table, the problem was not link to rtbegin_dynamic.o,
crtend_android.o that if you specify -nostdlib option the program is created but no work (Table Simbol empty)
nm (list symbols from object files) eg: nm test

gcc is not a compiler, it is a driver that controls the execution
of other applications that are what make the job
for example try invoque the compiler using -### as unique option for see details

LDFLAGS: are the flags for the linker

CFLAGS: are the flags to the compiler (not links)

Anyway if you are new to the compilation, even in cross compiling strongly
recommend you use the Android.mk way 
Sorry for my English ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not new to compilation, but yes worked less on android device..also, I didn't understand this part.."the problem was not link to rtbegin_dynamic.o, crtend_android.o that if you specify -nostdlib option the program is created but no work (Table Simbol empty) nm (list symbols from object files) eg: nm test"

Comment: Also, could understand, "invoque the compiler using -### as unique option for see details"

Comment: From man gcc: -###
Like -v except the commands are not executed and arguments are quoted unless they contain only alphanumeric characters or "./-_".  This is useful for shell scripts to capture the driver-generated command lines.

Comment: nm is a program: GNU nm lists the symbols from object files objfile.... If no object files are listed as arguments, nm assumes the file a.out.

Comment: GNU nm lists the symbols from object files objfile....  If no object
files are listed as arguments, nm assumes the file a.out.

Comment: -nostdlib is an option for the linker: -nostdlib Only search library directories explicitly specified on the command line. Library directories specified in linker scripts (including linker scripts specified on the command line) are ignored.

Comment: How do we compile the same program, Android.mk way?

Answer (score 1):

```
#Android.mk
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS) 
#module name
LOCAL_MODULE    := test  
#src
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.c
#build executable
include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)
```

export PATH=path_to_ndk_root:$PATH

export NDK_PROJECT_PATH=.

ndk-build APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=Android.mk